# How to initialize ThreadLocal<List<Object>>

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, thread-local

Following is my code, in which I am declaring a `ThreadLocal` variable:

```
public static final ThreadLocal<List<Object>> ARGS = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

I'm using this variable in the below snippet:

```
private static void getParams(Token... tokens) {
    if(ARGS == null) {
        new LinkedList<>();
    }
    if(tokens.length > 2) {
        for(Token token : Arrays.copyOfRange(tokens, 2, tokens.length)) {
            ARGS.get().add(ArgHelper.resolveArg(token));
        }
    }
}
```

The below line:

```
ARGS.get().add(ArgHelper.resolveArg(token));
```

is giving me `NullPointerException` thou I'm getting value from `ArgHelper.resolveArg(token)`.

Comment: The line `new LinkedList<>();` makes no sense. Can you post the stack exception?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.weather.bigweb.steps.keywords.Exec.getParams(Exec.java:77)
 at com.weather.bigweb.steps.keywords.Exec.exec(Exec.java:53)
 at com.weather.bigweb.steps.helper.KeywordHelper.execKeyword(KeywordHelper.java:40)
 at com.weather.bigweb.steps.helper.Step.step(Step.java:53)
 ... 20 more

Comment: Still not relevant, how do you know that `ARGS.get().add(ArgHelper.resolveArg(token));` throws the `NPE`?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

```
if(ARGS == null) {
  new LinkedList<>();
}
```

doesn't do anything. `ARGS` is created as a `final` non-null value, so this block will never be entered. Even if it did, calling `new LinkedList<>();` all alone simply constructs a `LinkedList` instance that immediately falls out of scope and is garbage collected. Nothing can reference it.

To properly initialize a `ThreadLocal` look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), which provides an example showing how to set an initial-value (by overriding the aptly-named [`initialValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#initialValue--) method).

You can do something similar:

```
public static final ThreadLocal<List<Object>> ARGS = new ThreadLocal<List<Object>>() {
  @Override protected List<Object> initialValue() {
    return new LinkedList<>();
  }
};
```

That said, some pointers:

- You should prefer `ArrayList` over `LinkedList` in almost all cases.
- Make `ARGS` `private` unless absolutely necessary. It's generally best to minimize the visibility of `ThreadLocal` instances, e.g. limiting it to the containing class, and exposing a nicer API to users of that class.
- Consider a more meaningful type than `List<Object>` - you force all users to inspect and cast the contents of the list if it can hold any `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8**

```
private static final ThreadLocal<List<Object>> list = 
    ThreadLocal.withInitial(ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use `ThreadLocal`.

Instead of your broken code, you probably want the following to initialize an empty thread-local.

```
if(ARGS.get() == null) {
    ARGS.set(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

Of course I'd advise against using `ThreadLocal` at all, especially if you don't have experience with using it.